# On input does not work after preventDefault

Tags: javascript, form-submit, preventdefault

I am making simple auth form with some messages for user while he is typing the username/email in the input. Before form submission code works just fine, but after I submit the form (with preventDefault) this 'input-checker' stops working. Can anyone tell me why and how to make it work?:-)

```
var reValidEmail = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

$("#auth-input").on('input', function () {
    if (document.getElementById("auth-input").value.indexOf("@") + 1) {
        if (!reValidEmail.test(document.getElementById("auth-input").value)) {
            $("#login-comment").text("Please enter valid email");
        } else {
            $("#login-comment").text("");
        }
    }
});

$("#log-in-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (     document.getElementById("auth-input").value.length > 0
        && ( document.getElementById("auth-input").value.indexOf("@") == -1
             || ( document.getElementById("auth-input").value.indexOf("@") + 1
                  && reValidEmail.test(document.getElementById("auth-input").value)
                )
           )
    ) {
        //some ajax request
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById("auth-input").value.indexOf("@") + 1) {
            $("#login-comment").text("Please enter valid email"); //does not hide after form submission and input change for correct one
        } else {
            $("#login-comment").text("Please enter username or email"); //does not hide after form submission and input change for correct one
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you modify the DOM after you submit the form? Does it replace the `#auth-input` field?

Comment: return false does the trick!

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, it's the same as `e.preventDefault()`.